# Python Style - print() with with joined strings

Tags: python-3.x

its just an Question about Python Coding Style. 
What would be the "correct" according to PEP-8?

```
print("I am an String of " + str(integer) + " Numbers long!")
print("I am an String of "+str(integer)+" Numbers long!")
```

In my opinion the upper is better readable.
The lower one would aggree better with the PEP-8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id26)

Comment: If you're printing it you can just do `print("I am a string of", integer, "Numbers long!")`. Or use one of the various string formatting methods rather than concatenation. Also it's not clear why you think the lower one, *without* spaces around the operators, agrees with PEP8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite the opposite, if you read the [Other Recomendations section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), you will notice that it is prefered to have your addition spaced out as in line 1.

In general, I recommend you do not put that much effort in finding the exact PEP8 practice for such small details, instead rely on the much simpler [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3) to give you a general idea of what is best. In that case,

> Sparse is better than dense.
>
> Readability counts.

You could also do the following.

```
print("I am an String of {} Numbers long!".format(integer))
```

And for Python 3.6 and above.

```
print(f"I am an String of {integer} Numbers long!")
```